# RStudio throws continuous "Error: bad binding access " errors and has to be killed

Tags: r, loops, binding, rstudio

I am using RStudio (RStudio 2023.12.1+402 "Ocean Storm" Release (4da5832, 2024-01-28) for windows
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) RStudio/2023.12.1+402 Chrome/116.0.5845.190 Electron/26.2.4 Safari/537.36) with R 4.3.0 Patched.

Recently (with no version change) RStudio has started to consistently flow the console with "Error: bad binding accesss". New error lines do not stop appearing, with no trackback info shown, so RStudio has to be stopped (usually with the task manager.) These errors only appear when the code includes a loop. Sometimes changing the name of the loop variable & rerunning the code will make the error disappear, but this is not consistent. The code itself is fine and runs for example in Visual Studio Code with no issues, so there isn't really any point in showing a specific code here. The only criteria I can see is that this will only happen in loops.

I have reinstalled RStudio but this didn't change anything.

Anyone has had the same problem and any idea of a fix ?

I have resinstalled RStudio with no success and I have used Visual Studio Code to run the same code with no problem.

Comment: What is the "patched" in "R 4.3.0 Patched"?

Comment: This is not new, https://forum.posit.co/t/rstudio-error-bad-binding-access/181302 ... (and was not resolved). https://forum.posit.co/t/error-bad-binding-access/179455/2 (earlier) suggests that a downgrade resolved the issue.

Comment: Similarly, https://forum.posit.co/t/bad-binding-access-while-using-mlr-within-a-loop/179571 suggests a downgrade too.

Comment: On GH, https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/12456 suggests it self-resolved with a later version of RStudio, while https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/14222 is still open. I suggest you comment on the latter open-issue with your system information and any more context.

Comment: https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/rpatched.html is R 4.3.0 patched, introduced to fix some bugs (including in file attachements in blastula)

Comment: funny ... I've been using R for over 10 years now, much of that on windows, and I don't think I ever grabbed "R Patched"!